# No such file or directory when executing an existing file

Tags: linux, bash, unix, android

I have norrowed the error down to this from a larger script and I'm getting the error "No such file or directory" when I try to execute a file which exist and I have the correct permissions for.

```
fabe@devweb:~$ ls -la /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.0/aapt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 fabe fabe 1264873 Mar 17 10:12 /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.0/aapt
fabe@devweb:~$ /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.0/aapt
-bash: /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.0/aapt: No such file or directory
```

Comment: is aapt a script? and something it is trying to open internally is not available?

Comment: try `sh /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.0/aapt`, and if that fails, put a sudo on the front. you may be losing read on the path leading up to the file.

Comment: It seems to be a binary file.

Comment: Frank Thomas, that does in fact give a different output indicating it may be a permission problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386392/aapt-not-found-under-the-right-path) the common issue may come from missing x86_32 libraries on x64 environment:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```